# How to select differences using three tables?

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

I need to run a script in order to fix some rows from my table company_menu.
However, I can't build this query to get these registers.
I build the schema in this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab86b

Below I show the expected result.

companies

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | company 1 |
| 2 | company 2 |
| 3 | company 3 |

menu_items

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | home |
| 2 | charts |
| 3 | users |
| 4 | projects |

company_menu

| id | company_id | menu_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

This is a result that I expected:

| id | company_id | menu_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |

```
CREATE TABLE companies(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50)
 );
 
CREATE TABLE menu_items(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50)
 );
 
CREATE TABLE company_menu(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  company_id INT,
  menu_item_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES companies(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(menu_item_id) REFERENCES menu_items(id)
);

INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES ("Company 1"),("Company 2"),("Company 3");
INSERT INTO menu_items (name) VALUES ("home"),("charts"),("users"),("projects");
INSERT INTO company_menu (company_id, menu_item_id) VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2),(1,3),(1,4);
INSERT INTO company_menu (company_id, menu_item_id) VALUES (2, 1),(2,3);
```

Comment: Providing a fiddle is very good! But make sure to also include the necessary DDL and DML in the question itself too. If the fiddle goes down for whatever reason that information gets lost and the question is worthless for future readers.

Comment: That's not "pivoting".  Pivoting would produce a table with 3 rows (companies) and 4 columns (menus).  (Or vice versa.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I can think of. Don't know which is more efficient. Both start with a full compannies-menu_items join to get all possible combinations, and then cut out the existing:

1. `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
select c.id company_id, m.id menu_item_id
from companies c
join menu_items m
where not exists (
  select * from company_menu where company_id = c.id and menu_item_id = m.id
);
```

2. `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL`:

```
select c.id company_id, m.id menu_item_id
from companies c
join menu_items m
left join company_menu cm on cm.company_id = c.id and cm.menu_item_id = m.id
where cm.id is null;
```

Both are sortable on any company or menu_item column.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab86b/11

Comment: `*` isn't necessary in exists